# How to compile against dynamic lib, not static, in codeblocks

Tags: mysql, dynamic, static, codeblocks

I'm using codeblocks to compile an app which uses mysql.  Under CentOS 6 this app compiles fine (and I assumed used the .so file). Under CentOS 5 this same project file won't compile unless I go the to Project|Build Options|Linker|Link Libraries and add:

***/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a***

Otherwise I get linking errors like

***myfile.c|87|undefined reference to `mysql_use_result'|***

1. Does that mean under CentOS 6 the linker is using the dynamic .so file, but under CentOS 5 it's using the static .a file?
2. Is there a way to configure my project so that it links using the dynamic .so file too?
3. I also have to add "libresolv" and "libssl" to the linker libraries or I got lots of errors.  (And under CentOS 6 I don't).  Is this the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.

The first is that the correct way to link against mysql is to add `-lmysqlclient` to the link line, instead of attempting to link the static library directly. When you add `-lx` to the link line, the linker will search `LDPATH` for a file named `libx.so` (if a dynamic link) or `libx.a` (if a static link).

You should double-check that `libmysqlclient.so` is in the `LDPATH` **and is a compatible architecture** (keep in mind 64-bit vs 32-bit issues).

The reason you need to add `-lresolv` and `-lssl` as well under CentOS 6 is that the MySQL library no longer automatically pulls them in - in previous versions, it always would, but in CentOS 6 it properly does not. Generally you can use `pkg-config` to see what you need to link a certain library (or look at its `.la` file, if it installed one). You could also use `libtool` to do the linking, but I don't recommend that.